# How to accomplish repetitive regex replace

Tags: javascript, regex, vbscript

I want to replace following in single stroke.

```
With regEx_
 .Global = True
 .MultiLine = True
 .IgnoreCase = True    
.Pattern = "xxxxxx(.*)[\r\n]+xxxxxx"
TextLine = regEx_.replace(TextLine, "xxxxxx$1,")
.Pattern = "xxxxxx(.*)[\r\n]+xxxxxx"
TextLine = regEx_.replace(TextLine, "xxxxxx$1,")
.Pattern = "xxxxxx(.*)[\r\n]+xxxxxx"
TextLine = regEx_.replace(TextLine, "xxxxxx$1,")
.Pattern = "xxxxxx(.*)[\r\n]+xxxxxx"
TextLine = regEx_.replace(TextLine, "xxxxxx$1,")
End With
```

The Ides is to delimit the lines

**For example:**

**From This,**

```
xxxxxx1
xxxxxx2
xxxxxx3
xxxxxx4
```

To this.

```
xxxxxx1,2,3,4
```

I want to repeat until no match remains to be found.

**EDIT**

Lines are not exclusive in string but a part of strin like

```
yzyzyz#
xxxxxx1
xxxxxx2
xxxxxx3
xxxxxx4
yzyzyz*
xxxxxx1
xxxxxx2
```

Comment: I don't know VBscript - is there a way to apply a regex more than once (usually the `/g` modifier)? Try that or just apply the regular expression in a loop until it no longer matches.

Comment: I also much don't know VBscript but as it's only choice for windows, I am using it. I think `.Global = True` does that trick.

Comment: Should the `xxxxx(.*)` follow one another? Or do you also have `xxxxx2yyyyy3xxxxx4`?

Comment: @Wiktor: Yes to the first question. it is as per shown in my example.

Comment: Well, I just thought you could match all `xxxxxx(.*)`, and just build the result with `xxxxx` and then adding `,` + the submatches. Not sure it will solve this issue though.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I think it is better to stick to what I am doing. IE repeated find and replace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the global flag:

```
input.replace(/[\r\n]+xxxxxx/g, ',')
// output: xxxxxx1,2,3,4
```

Using VBScript, it would looks like this:

```
Dim TextLine, regEx_
TextLine = "xxxxxx1" & VbCrLf & _
           "xxxxxx2" & VbCrLf & _
           "xxxxxx3" & VbCrLf & _
           "xxxxxx4"

Set regEx_ = new regexp
With regEx_
 .Global = True
 .MultiLine = True
 .IgnoreCase = True
 .Pattern = "[\r\n]+xxxxxx"
TextLine = regEx_.replace(TextLine, ",")
End With
```

Comment: Sorry to forget to mention that it also have other lines in the string. I like the Idea though but it will disturb overall pattern. See my latest updated question **Edit**

Comment: This would have been possible with a lookbehind: `(?<=xxxxxx\d)[\r\n]xxxxxx(\d+)`. Unfortunately, this is not supported by VBScript regexp.

Comment: No problem. I can use jscript. I will try and update.

Comment: Lookbehind are not either supported by JavaScript regexp.

Comment: Sorry as novice, How to accomplish look behind. Perl?

Comment: Yes, lookbehinds are fully supported by PCRE (Perl, PHP, R, Ruby, Python, Java; .NET...)